# Ошибка библиотеки: Error:(19, 20) error: no suitable method found for show

Tags: android

В чем может быть проблема?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        android.app.DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }
}
```

Подчеркивает "getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker"" и пишет:

> "Error:(19, 20) error: no suitable
> method found for
> show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager,String)
> method
> DialogFragment.show(android.app.FragmentManager,String)
> is not applicable (argument mismatch;
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
> cannot be converted to
> android.app.FragmentManager) method
> DialogFragment.show(FragmentTransaction,String)
> is not applicable (argument mismatch;
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
> cannot be converted to
> FragmentTransaction)"

И последний импорт "серый", т.е. не используется. В папке libs android-support-v4.jar есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам следует использовать `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`, но вместо него вы используете `android.app.DialogFragment`:

> **android.app.DialogFragment** newFragment = new TimePickFragment();

Убедитесь, что `TimePickFragment` наследуется от нужного `DialogFragment`.

Comment: Спасибо. Вообще, это отсюда: http://androiddocs.ru/vidzhet-vybora-vremeni-timepicker/

android.app там и не должно быть, это появилось, когда я подключал библиотеки. Теперь у меня точь в точь как и в источнике, но подчеркивает DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickFragment(); и пишет: "Incopatible types Required:android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
Found: com.hangover.a52_timepickerdialog.TimePickFragment "

Comment: @compl, очевидно, `TimePickFragment` наследуется от `android.app.DialogFragment`, а должен от `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`.

Comment: @falstaf, спасибо, понял и исправил. Но теперь вылетает это:
"08-11 22:54:41.888    1913-1913/com.hangover.a52_timepickerdialog E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hangover.a52_timepickerdialog, PID: 1913
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:104)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
            ..."

Comment: @compl, подключите `support v7` как `library project`.

Comment: @falstaf, не совсем понял. У меня android studio, я просто скопировал из sdk android-support-v4.jar и android-support-v7-appcompat.jar в папку libs  в проекте и всё.

Comment: > я просто скопировал из sdk android-support-v4.jar и android-support-v7-appcompat.jar в папку libs в проекте и всё.

В том-то и проблема. Вы только `.jar` скопировали от `support library v7`, а ресурсы не подключили, о чём в вышеприведённом стектрейсе и говорится. Подключите весь `android-support-v7-appcompat` как `library project`.

Comment: Но а как подключить эти ресурсы?